# Analytic solution for partial differential equation (Eigenvalues and eigenfunctions)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

Given $\Sigma_\epsilon = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:|\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-1|\le \epsilon \}$ for some small $\epsilon>0$

I want to determine(analytically) all the functions $u$ and constants $\lambda$ (eigenfunctions and eigenvalues?) which satisfy the following conditions.

$-\Delta u=\lambda u $ for $(x,y) \in \Sigma_\epsilon$

and

$ \vec{n} \cdot \nabla u=0$ for $(x,y) \in \partial\Sigma_\epsilon$ (the boundary of $\Sigma_\epsilon$)

where $\Delta$ is the standard Laplacian, $ \vec{n}$ is the normal vector (normal to the boundary of $\Sigma_\epsilon$), $\nabla$ is the gradient.

I think the region is somehow 'circular' thus i tried to convert it to polar coordinate but wasn't able to solve it.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The region is an annulus. i.e., the area between two concentric circles. In this case the circles are centered at the origin, and the inside one radius $1- \epsilon$ while the outside has radius $1 + \epsilon$. And yes, what you are after are eigenvalues $\lambda$ and corresponding eigenfunctions $u$ of the laplacian.